# How and where do i use the i++ operator in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was wondering if anyone could tell me about the `i++` operator in C#.

I know it adds one to the int value, but I wouldn't have a clue where to use it, and if its only for loop statements, or can be used in general projects.

If I could get some practical examples of where you might use the `i++` operator, thank you.

Comment: You would use it any time you wanted to increment an integer.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, not only integers, see the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w(v=vs.100).aspx). The example explains very well how it works

Comment: Just a sidenote: people coming from the C++ world to C#, usually use ++i instead of i++.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I know why you're saying that (i.e. why should adding 1 be a special case?), but `i++` (or `++i`) is a pretty-well engrained idiom in the C-like languages.

Comment: @kol:  Not necessarily. `++i` vs `i++` is one of those premature optimizations nowadays. I haven't seen many people using the former more often than the latter in the C++ I've worked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `i++` is just like `x == y > 0 ? x : z` which both are syntactic sugar.

`x = i++` saves you the space of writing `x=i; i=i+1;`

Is it good or bad? There is really no exact answer to this.

I personally avoid these expressions as they make my code look complex, sometimes hard to debug. Always think code **readability** instead of **write-ability**, always think how your code looks readable instead of how easy is it to write it

Answer (score 6):

This is `post-increment`,which means that the increment will be done after the execution of the statement

```
int i=0;
Console.Write(i++);  // still 0
Console.Write(i);    // prints 1, it is incremented
```

Comment: Not really answering the question. The OP knows what it does and asks _when_ to use it.

Answer (score 3):

In general, given this declaration:

```
var myNum = 0;
```

anywhere you would normally do this:

```
myNum += 1;
```

You could just do this:

```
myNum++;
```

Comment: Not really answering the question. The OP knows what it does and asks _when_ to use it.

Comment: I could certainly go into a more in-depth discussion of the (pre|post)fix (in|de)crement operators, but I guess it just seems too obvious. Anywhere you might increment by one, you can use this operator, taking special care of when the increment actually happens. I'm not sure any more example is warranted.

Answer (score 3):

What you are referring to is the C# post increment operator, common use case are :

- Incrementing the counter variable in a standard for loop
- Incrementing the counter variable in a while loop
- Accessing an array in sequential order **(3)**

Example **(3)** :

```
int[] table = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
int i = 0;
int j = table[i++]; //Access the table array element 0
int k = table[i++]; //Access the table array element 1
int l = table[i++]; //Access the table array element 2
```

So, whats the post increment operator really does ? 
**It return the value of the variable and then increment it's value by 1 unit .**